# How to receive messages with SignalR inside a Python Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, signalr

I have the following piece of code below and i use the function sendMessageToClient1 to send messages to the hub and it works perfectly, but i can't receive messages from the hub using the line 
self.chat.client.on("broadcastMessage", self.sendMessageToClient). How can i receive messages from inside a class?

```
from requests import Session
from signalr import Connection
import threading, time, json, logging



class Broker:
    def __init__(self, cli):
        self.cli = cli
        logging.info("registered the cli (main thread)")

    def launch(self):
      try:
        with Session() as session:
            logging.info("inside new session")
            self.connection = Connection("http://localhost:5000/signalr", session)
            logging.info("got the connection")
            self.chat = self.connection.register_hub('chathub')
            logging.info("got the hub")
            self.connection.start()
            logging.info("started the connection")
            self.chat.client.on("broadcastMessage", self.sendMessageToClient)
            logging.info("registered the receiver function")
      except:
        logging.error("error on the creation of the message broker")



    def sendMessageToClient(self, message):
      try:
        logging.info("received message")
        self.chat.server.invoke("ackMessage", message["id"])
        self.cli.sendMessage(message["clientNumber", "messageBody"])
      except:
        logging.error("error receiving a message from the message broker")

    def sendMessageToClient1(self, message):
      try:
        print("sending message " + json.dumps(message))
        self.chat.server.invoke("send", json.dumps(message))
      except:
        logging.error("error sending a message to the broker.")
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: No sorry, I ended up giving up on using it with Python and used C# instead, pretty easy to use and play around with

Comment: Ah that's annoying - I've managed to get a Python Client / C# Server working if you're still interested using the library linked below. Anyway - obrigado for the reply https://github.com/slazarov/python-signalr-client

Comment: I'll give it a try, thanks!